# Kafka producer throws "Received unknown topic or partition error" when sending to topic created via AdminClient createTopics method

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have issue with topics created using `AdminClient createTopics`.
In my application I have following sequence:

1. create new topic with 1 partition, replication factor set to 1 using `AdminClient.createTopics`
2. wait on`AdminClient.createTopics` `KafkaFuture` result
3. immediately send a new message to newly created topic (usually the time between operation 2 and 3 is about 200 milliseconds).

My code is as follows:

```
adminClient
  .createTopics(Collections.singleton(new NewTopic(targetTopic, 1, (short) 1)))
  .values()
  .get(targetTopic)
  .get();
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(targetTopic, data));
```

From time to time producer doesn't see the created topic and throws following exception:

> [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {targetTopic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
>
> [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received unknown topic or partition error in produce request on partition targetTopic. The topic/partition may not exist or the user may not have Describe access to it

This issue is very rare (< 0,1% all created topics).

Is it guaranteed that when `AdminClient.createTopics` Kafka future is completed then topic is created and Kafka producer should see that topic ?
If not then which method of topic creation can give me such guarantee ?

I am using kafka-clients:2.0.0 and Kafka HD service on Azure. My cluster consists of 3 Zookeeper and 3 Kafka nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka client is not guarenteed about atomic topic creation. You can read it from this [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#createTopics-java.util.Collection-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsOptions-). When you create a topic, kafka will notify distributed systems about topics information so the action is running on different machines and these can't be atomic without distributed transactional management.

Comment: Thank you for answer, is there any mechanism that could give me guarantee that topic was really created ? I was thinking about enabling topic auto creation on Kafka broker (which I don't really want due to security reasons) or setting replication factor value equal to number of nodes.

Comment: I don't know any mechanism for this but you can write it. After creation check the topic information in a loop if information is correct then break the loop do next step. But If you can split the creation of topic and publication step this could be better i think.